# Problems using Mendeley API in a virtual environment

Tags: python

I tried to use the Mendeley SDK and I'm having some problems. I already set the virtual environment and installed the Mendeley package but still I cant make work the code. As far as I can understand the following response it's because something in the virtual environment or in the mendeley package is not working, can someone tell me what should I do next

I used this code which I found in: [Authentication issue in mendeley Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777288/authentication-issue-in-mendeley-python-sdk/48751456#48751456)

```
client_id = 1
client_secret = "XXXXXXXXX"

redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/testing"

from mendeley import Mendeley

# These values should match the ones supplied when registering your application.
mendeley = Mendeley(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

auth = mendeley.start_implicit_grant_flow()

# The user needs to visit this URL, and log in to Mendeley.
login_url = auth.get_login_url()

import requests

res = requests.post(login_url, allow_redirects = False, data = {
    'username': 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    'password': 'xxxxx'
})

auth_response = res.headers['Location']

# After logging in, the user will be redirected to a URL, auth_response.
session = auth.authenticate(auth_response)

print(session.files.list().items)
```

After I made added the info needed to access the API I get this response:

```
(VEnv_Mendeley_v2) C:\Users\rafae\Pictures\Mend\mendeley-api-python-catalog-example-master>py otromendeley.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rafae\Pictures\Mend\mendeley-api-python-catalog-example-master\otromendeley.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mendeley import Mendeley
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\mendeley\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from mendeley.auth import MendeleyClientCredentialsAuthenticator, \
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\mendeley\auth.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "C:\python\Mendeley\VEnv_Mendeley_v2\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870041/cannot-import-name-mutablemapping-from-collections)

Comment: Please also take a look to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html). Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 3.10: Moved Collections Abstract Base Classes to the collections.abc module. For backwards compatibility, they continue to be visible in this module through Python 3.9.